# UrlHelper and ViewContext inside an Authorization Attribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, httpcontext, custom-attributes

I have a scenario that I haven't been able to solve:

I'm toying around with creating my own custom authorization attribute for mvc. The main bit of functionality I would like to add is to have the ability to change where the user gets redirected if they are not in a certain role. I don't mind that the system sends them back to the login page if they're not authenticated, but I would like to choose where to send them if they are authenticated but not allowed to access that action method.

Here's is what I would like to do:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
        public string Action;
        public string Controller;

        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            // if User is authenticated but not in the correct role
            string url = Url.Action(this.Action, this.Controller);                
            httpContext.Response.Redirect(url);
        }
    }
```

And as an added bonus I would like to have access to ViewContext and TempData before I do the redirect.

Any thoughts on how I could get instantiate a UrlHelper and ViewContext in the attribute?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could override the [`OnAuthorization`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.onauthorization.aspx) method:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
    }

    // Call the AuthorizeCore which should return true or false
    if (!this.AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext))
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary()
        {
            { "controller", "home" },
            { "action", "about" },
            { "id", "foo" },
        });
    }
}
```

As far as ViewData and TempData are concerned: `filterContext.Controller.ViewData` and `filterContext.Controller.TempData` should work inside the `OnAuthorization` method. And finally if you wish to use an `UrlHelper` (in this case there's no need because `RedirectToRouteResult` is better) you could instantiate it:

```
var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);
```

Comment: Brilliant, thx. After looking at your response I realized I could have simply asked "How do I go about getting the AuthorizationContext." Once I have that I'm dangerous.

Comment: Note: Implementing an OnAuthorization() method is not a trivial exercise.  If you choose to override OnAuthorization() instead of AuthorizeCore(), please add code in OnAuthorization() to disable or hook output caching.  See http://forums.asp.net/p/1533590/3737756.aspx for more information.